# How to dynamically update content in WPForms based on select box choice?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wpforms

I've been exploring WPForms and noticed a dynamic content update feature in some examples on websites. Specifically, after a visitor selects an option from a select box, the content below or above it changes dynamically, such as updating the displayed price.

I'm interested in implementing a similar functionality in WPForms but couldn't find an option in the plugin to enable this feature. Could someone guide me on how to achieve dynamic content updates based on select box choices in WPForms?

I appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction. Thank you!